ansible 2.10 / lineinfile: regexp: "{{netw}}" variable is not dissolved
`
- name: read network
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    CUSTOMER: "{{ CUST | default("me") }}"
    list: " {{ lookup('file', 'networks').split('\n')[0] }} "
    gway: " {{ list.split(' ')[2] }} "
    netw: " {{ list.split(' ')[1] }} "
  tasks:
    - name: test1
      lineinfile:
        path: 'networks'
        state: absent
        regexp: "{{netw}}"
    - debug:
        var: gway
    - debug:
        var: netw

The variable netw printed in output correct: my networks file has networks and gateways example:
172.16.25.0/29 172.16.25.1
but not delete the line from file.
if i write this hard coded it's working: regexp: "172.16.25.1"

OK i found the error. The whitespaces in vars assignment was the problem.

the correct code is this:
- name: read network
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list: "{{lookup('file', 'networks').split('\n')[0]}}"
    gway: "{{list.split(',')[2]}}"
    netw: "{{list.split(',')[1]}}"
    line_to_remove: "{{netw}}"
  tasks:
    - name: test1
      lineinfile:
        path: "networks"
        state: absent
        regexp: '{{ line_to_remove | regex_escape() }}'
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ line_to_remove }}"

